# Python libraries missing in docker container after they were installed on img build

Tags: python, docker, pip, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

I'm building an image with some Python packages, here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add bash gcc musl-dev
RUN apk add python3 python3-dev
RUN apk add py3-pip
RUN apk add libxslt-dev libxml2-dev

ENV PROJECT_HOME /opt/app

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/modules

# This is needed for Jep, otherwise it doesn't run
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jep
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so

RUN pip3 install jep
RUN pip3 install googleads
RUN pip3 install gspread
RUN pip3 list

COPY target/my-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar $PROJECT_HOME/my-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME

CMD ["java", "-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://my-mongo:27017/mydb","-jar","./my-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Now, even though I see the installed packages at build time (and it's a big list that pip3 list returns..., when I start the container, I don't see on it any of the packages installed out of jep.

```
/opt/app # pip3 list
jep (3.7.1)
pip (9.0.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)
/opt/app #
```

This is how i'm building the image:

```
docker build -t my-server .
```

And this is how I'm checking the installed libs:

```
bash -c "clear && docker exec -it my-server sh"

pip3 list
```

The interesting part is that the *same* "pip3 list" command ran at build time returns the whole list of libs, but inside of the container, just a few of them...

**UPDATE 1**
It turns out that if I start the container manually, I indeed see all the libs, but I've been (and I have to) starting the container with docker-compose. And somehow when I do that I don't see all the libs, this is my docker-compose config for that image:

```
services:
  my-server:
    build: .
    restart: always
    container_name: my-server
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    working_dir: /opt/app
    volumes:
      - $HOME/data/Modules:/opt/app/modules
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: I got to successfully run your dockerfile (except for part with jar file) and pip list worked just fine giving me list of libs including googleads and it's dependencies. How are you getting into container to check `pip list`?

Comment: Wow, I'm more confused now. I've just added it to the post, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Could you try overriding command from default to just bash? Like this `docker run -ti --rm my-server bash`. If it still doesn't work, try removing `COPY target/my-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar $PROJECT_HOME/my-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` from dockerfile, rebuilding it and running again with overwritten command. Thus it should be identical to my local dockerfile

Comment: @AndreyBondar see UPDATE 1, somehow the problem seems to be with docker-compose, any ideas?

Comment: Try removing volume from compose file - may be there is some problem with it, even though I can't reproduce it at the moment

Comment: Changed build . to image: my-server and seems to work. Still checking

Comment: How are you starting container? Just by `docker-compose up -d`? Did you rebuild it between attempts with `docker-compose build`?

Comment: I've been building the image with docker build and starting it with docker-compose. I thought that was ok.
Now when I run docker-compose build I get this error: docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-osxkeychain exited with "The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.".',)

Comment: Are you running on mac OS? If so then this topic could help https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/82

Comment: It works! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @AndreyBondar, It works!

I was building the image with docker and running it with docker-compose who was trying to build it also but it couldn't because of that OSX authentication issue, so it seems that it was running a previous version of the image without the libraries (not 100% but that's what it looks).

So unchecked the "Securely store Docker logins in macOs keychain" option from the docker settings now it works, and the image gets built perfectly with docker-compose.